# Help with this issue

Tags: c++, math, geometry

My application allows rotating points around a center based on the mouse position. I'm basically rotating points around another point like this:

```
void CGlEngineFunctions::RotateAroundPointRad( const POINTFLOAT &center, const POINTFLOAT &in, POINTFLOAT &out, float angle )
{
 //x' = cos(theta)*x - sin(theta)*y
 //y' = sin(theta)*x + cos(theta)*y

 POINTFLOAT subtr;
 subtr.x = in.x - center.x;
 subtr.y = in.y - center.y;

 out.x = cos(angle)*subtr.x - sin(angle)*subtr.y;
 out.y = sin(angle)*subtr.x + cos(angle)*subtr.y;

 out.x += center.x;
 out.y += center.y;
}
```

where POINTFLOAT is simply

```
struct POINTFLOAT {
float x;
float y;
}
```

The issue is that the points need to be updated on mousemove. I am looking for a way to do this without doing the following:

```
Store original points
Rotate Original points
Copy result
Show Result
Rotate Original points
Copy result
Show Result....
```

I feel storing the originals seems messy and uses extra memory. Is there a way, knowing the previous rotation angle and the current one that I can somehow avoid applying the transformation to the original points all the time and just build upon the points i'm modifying?

*the center will never change until mouse up so thats not an issue

Thanks

Comment: everytime i see a question tagged both c and c++ my head wants to explode

Comment: will the head [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) if it is tagged with [c, c++ and php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20c%2b%2b%20php)? :p

Comment: Also, this seems to be a mathematical based question, i.e. might find better answers on math.stackexchange .

Comment: @KennyTM, don't make me retag those...

Comment: @James: Hey, maybe one of them is validly about all 3.... But I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Do not store the temporary points meanwhile the mouse is being used. Always rotate the original object, until the mouse is released. You only need to track the last angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract the old rotation from the new one, you'll get a value you should be able to use to rotate the already-modified points.  Note that this requires storing the old rotation, and the coordinates will get less and less accurate the more you translate them around.  It's close enough for government work, though.

Comment: So if ang was 3 and now its 4, I only need to rotate by 1 type thing?

Comment: @Milo: Right.  That should work OK.  Reread the part about the coordinates losing accuracy though -- if this is going to happen a lot with the same points, rounding errors might mess you up.

Comment: Would this margin of error every be visibly noticeable? I'm rotating polygons in a  vector drawing application.

Comment: What I mean is will it get increasingly worse the longer I keep my mouse moving?

Comment: Yes.  It'll slowly get worse.  It'll start out unnoticeable, but the errors will accumulate slowly each time the points rotate.  It should take a bunch of rotations for the error to become noticeable, though.

Answer (score 1):

So, instead of storing the previous point, you'd rather store the previous angle?

Perhaps I can discourage you from doing that. Instead of keeping a struct of two floats, you'd keep a single float (angle), but add complexity to the application, for very little gain.

Revisit that code in 6 months and you'll wonder why you spent all that time fiddling with trigonometry just to save one float.

My 2¢. It is an interesting trig problem nonetheless :)

Comment: No, its not just to save 2 floats, it wouldnt be just 1 point, it might be thousands which means on mouse down copy thousands of points, then modify the originals on first mouse move, then recopy old ones, then modify them etc, its a lot...

Comment: Oh, it's for a polygon! I see. Then, yes, cHao has the right of it.